# eval specific part within a string Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json

I have a following string

```
var popupValue = { "empID": "jQuery('#3566_textbox').val()","empName": "jQuery('#3567_textbox').val()"};
```

i just want the output to be:

```
var popupValue = { "empID": "1","empName": "ABC"};
```

i am failing to parse my string, can someone help me on that

code i have tried:

```
var popupValue = { "empID": "eval(\"jQuery('#3566_textbox').val()\")","empName": "eval(\"jQuery('#3567_textbox').val()\")"};
```

i am getting parse exception

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an object and add the textbox values to it. WHat you are doing now is creating a string with the values `jQuery('#3566_textbox').val()` as part of that string, not as the actual textbox values.

```
<script>
    var jsonObject = new Object();
    jsonObject.empID = $('#3566_textbox').val();
    jsonObject.empName = $('#3567_textbox').val();

    var popupValue = JSON.stringify(jsonObject);

    console.log(popupValue);
</script>
```